# Unable to get the record from mongodb when querying with conditions in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the `collection` name `restaurant` and it have 1.2 million record .I want to find the restaurant which are near 1 mile radius based on my Geo location (i.e. lat/long)

**Sample**: here I have share 2 document out of 1.2 million of `restaurant` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5937aa44ae5fbf080d017fdc"),
    "factual_id" : "d37774d0-e379-4325-83ed-6fee2f6820f6",
    "name" : "Orange Deli Grocery",
    "address" : "145 Avenue D",
    "address_extended" : null,
    "po_box" : null,
    "locality" : "New York",
    "region" : "NY",
    "post_town" : null,
    "admin_region" : null,
    "postcode" : NumberInt("10009"),
    "country" : "us",
    "tel" : "(212) 228-2710",
    "fax" : null,
    "latitude" : 40.724909,
    "longitude" : -73.97533,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.97533,
            40.724909
        ]
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:6/7/2017, 1:06:53 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5937ad15ae5fbf8003000ff9"),
    "factual_id" : "18393fb5-6061-4281-84f5-d860d78e88a0",
    "name" : "El Rinconcito",
    "address" : "408 E 10th St",
    "address_extended" : "Frnt 2",
    "po_box" : null,
    "locality" : "New York",
    "region" : "NY",
    "post_town" : null,
    "admin_region" : null,
    "postcode" : NumberInt("10009"),
    "country" : "us",
    "tel" : "(212) 254-1381",
    "fax" : "(646) 590-3673",
    "latitude" : 40.725591,
    "longitude" : -73.976997,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.976997,
            40.725591
        ]
    }
}
```

Now when I run the below query in mongo shell I get 5000 record.

```
var query = {
    "loc" : {
        $geoWithin : {
            $centerSphere : [[-73.993068,40.722355], 1/3959 ]
        }
    }
};
// Step 2: Query points.
db.restaurant.find(query)
```

But when the same thing I try with `PHP` I get the empty response

```
$args = array(
    'loc' => array(
        "\$geoWithin" => array(
            "\$centerSphere" => array(
                array(-73.993068,40.722355), 1/3959 
            )
        )
    )
);

// here i have successfully connection with mongo
$collection = new MongoCollection($this->mongo_db->db, 'restaurant');
$cursor = $collection->find($args);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

Comment: Use single quotes `''` as in `'$geoWithin'` instead of the double quotes `""`

Comment: `$args = array(
            'loc' => array(
                '$geoWithin' => array(
                    '$centerSphere' => array(
                        array($long, $lat), $this->milesToRadian($mile)
                    )
                )
            )
        );` still not working @NeilLunn

Comment: Are you sure you are connected the correct database instance and name? Also check your variables actually hold the values you think they do.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I have connected to correct database because other query are working fine